# What do you get by finding all the weapons and items on a level?

Tags: hitman-absolution

On the summary screen of each level, the game tells you which weapons/items you found in the level. What sort of reward do I get for finding all of them for any given level? I have checked to make sure that they don't count as challenges.

Comment: Yep. Definitely duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in the lost and found section is just extras, except for some weapons and the disguises.

If you find the weapons that are in the safe house and the disguises then it becomes unlocked and you don't have to pay for them with your contract cash. The other items I think is just for replay value.